# Зависимости systemd от девайса

Tags: linux, systemd, внешние-устройства

Удев запускает

```
SUBSYSTEM=="input", KERNEL=="event[0-9]*", ENV{ID_USB_DRIVER}=="usbtouchscreen", SYMLINK+="input/ts",  MODE="0600" ,TAG+="systemd" ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="ts_uinput.service"
```

Сервис

```
[Unit]
Description=touchscreen input
BindsTo=dev-input-ts.device
After=dev-input-ts.device
RequiresMountsFor=/etc/ts.env

[Service]
Type=forking
EnvironmentFile=/etc/ts.env
ExecStartPre=/opt/ts/prestart.sh
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ts_uinput -v -d
ExecStartPost=/opt/ts/poststart.sh
```

В prestart выполняю калибровку тача. Но сервис с окошком запускается до запуска ts_uinput несмотря на зависимости

```
[Unit]
Description=Kiosk
Requires=ts_uinput.service
BindsTo=dev-input-ts_uinput.device

[Service]
Type=simple
EnvironmentFile=/etc/kiosk.env
ExecStart=/opt/kiosk/bin/kiosk
WorkingDirectory=/opt/kiosk/
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=30
User=kiosk

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`/dev/input/ts_uinput` ссылка создается udev на устройство созданное демоном `ts_uinput`

```
SUBSYSTEM=="input", KERNEL=="event[0-9]*", ATTRS{name}=="ts_uinput", SYMLINK+="input/ts_uinput",  MODE="0666"
```

Comment: `$ man systemd.unit`: «Requires= … Note that requirement dependencies do not influence the order in which services are started or stopped. This has to be configured independently with the After= or Before= options.» // т.е., если надо, чтобы kiosk.service запускался после ts_uinput.service, то `Requires=ts_uinput.service` надо заменить на (или добавить) `After=ts_uinput.service`. хотя, боюсь, это не поможет: я так понял, что ts_unput должен к моменту запуска kiosk не просто запуститься, а уже проделать какие-то действия. значит, логику придётся усложнять.

Comment: и After делал - не помонает. ExecStartPre нужно чтоб выполнился до старта киоска.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ "$(systemctl is-active ts_uinput)" == "activating" ]
do
sleep 1
done
```

скрипт в `ExecStartPre` сервиса киоска добавил.